# Public PostGIS Server available?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, free-software, hosting

Can anyone point me to a (if possible at all) list of public PostGIS Servers, where one can set up their own database/tables?

I would need a PostGIS server on 24h/7d while not having the resources by myself for multiple humanitarian projects in the south pacific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also take a look at [QGISCloud](https://qgiscloud.com/). You can use a QGIS plugin to connect/communicate with it, or do so directly as a PostGIS datasource.

Answer (score 4):

Here, you go: http://cartodb.com/

Under the covers it's all PostGIS/PostgreSQL.